# Can I add this code in the same plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have a plugin (called pluggable) that takes any `.plugin` and adds to it this markup

```
<span class="colorable">color me</span>
```

This is my original markup with class="plugin".

```
<div class="plugin"></div>
<div class="plugin"></div>
<div class="plugin"></div>
```

In js, I call `$('.plugin').pluggable();` which adds the `<span>` html above and makes it look like this

```
<div class="plugin"><span class="colorable">color me</span></div>
<div class="plugin"><span class="colorable">color me</span></div>
<div class="plugin"><span class="colorable">color me</span></div>
```

This is all the plugin does (adds this html) and the plugin itself is simple like this

```
(function($){
    $.fn.pluggable = function() {    
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).html('<span class="colorable">color me</span>');
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

But what I'm trying to really do is that after that, when a span with class .colorable is clicked, I want it to change its background color to red. I can do this with jquery like this

```
$('.colorable').click(function(){
   $this.css("background-color", "orange");
});
```

but is there a way to have this code contained in the same plugin so that the whole operation is self contained. I'm wondering because the original element that the plugin operates on is class `.plugin`, but the element that eventually gets colored is the new span markup that gets added `.colorable`. But I'd like to keep all this code for this operation in a single plugin/file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a `.click` handler to the `.colorable` spans once they have been inserted:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.pluggable = function() {    
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).html('<span class="colorable">color me</span>');
            $(this).find(".colorable").click(function() {
                $(this).css("background-color", "orange");
            });
        });               
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't replace the dom functions for creating new elements (`document.createElement('tagName')`) and it is very useful to learn how to use these together with jquery to structure your code better.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.pluggable = function() {    
        return this.each(function() {

            // Create the element
            var spanElement = document.createElement('span');
            // Set the class
            spanEleement.className = 'colorable';
            spanElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('color me'));
            // Add the event using jQuery
            $(spanElement).click(function() {
              $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
            });
            // Append it using jQuery function
            $(this).append(spanElement);
            // native function for this would be element.appendChild()

        });               
})( jQuery );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one,

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.pluggable = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var span  = $('<span class="colorable">color me</span>');
        span.click(function(){
               $(this).css("background-color", "orange");
        });
        $(this).append(span);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Do whatever you want, before append the element to DOM.